# Powershell invoke-restmethod variable in url

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, scripting, invoke

I am new to powershell, and I am trying to create a simple script that will allow me to turn on several Azure VMs using the invoke-restmethod.

My code works when instead of using a variable I directly write the VM name into the url, but I want to use a variable, since eventually this must work for more than one VM.

Relevant part of code:

```
$body = @{
"$virtualMachines" = "VM1"
} | ConvertTo=Json

$url= "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mySubscriptionId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/myLabName/virtualmachines/" + $virtualMachines + "/start?api-version=2018-09-15"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had a number of VMs, you could put them all into a PowerShell variable like this, an array of strings.

```
$VMs = "myVm1", "myVm2", "myVm3"
```

PowerShell has a number of flow control statements, the one you want to use is `ForEach`, which will step through an array one at a time.  We just modify the way you're setting up the URL to be friendlier and easier to read and this should work just fine.

```
$baseUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mySubscriptionId/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/myLabName/virtualmachines/"

ForEach ($vm in $VMs){
   $url = $baseurl + $vm + "/start?api-version=2018-09-15"
   Write-host "About to start [$Vm]"  
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers
   $response | ConvertTo-Json
}
```

I checked [the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start) for the `start?` REST API endpoint, and it doesn't look like you need the `-Body` parameter for this endpoint.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.